# Generate random Float number in xCode

Tags: objective-c

I'm using the  following code to generate a random Float number in XCode:

```
float randFloat = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 5.0 ;
```

The issue is that it's always give me the same number sequence even when I restart the simulator: -

0.000039
0.657689
3.778027
2.29351
etc.

Any idea how to fix this so that it generates random numbers every time?

Comment: Add `srand(time(NULL));` to start the seed.

Comment: Larme adding that now gives me values very close to each other and incrementing but not random.